# Loading jquery plugin result into Durandal view

Tags: durandal

I am using the Durandal Starter Template for mvc4.  I have set the following simple View:

```
<section>
    <h2 data-bind="html: displayName"></h2>
     <h3 data-bind="html: posts"></h3>
     <button data-bind="click: getrss">Get Posts</button>
     <div id="rsstestid" ></div>
</section>
```

and ViewModel:

```
    define(function (require) {
    var http = require('durandal/http'),
        app = require('durandal/app');

    return {
        displayName: 'This is my RssTest',
        posts: ko.observable(),
        activate: function () {
            return;
        },
        getrss: function () {
            $('#rsstestid').rssfeed('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews');
            return;
        }
    };
});
```

As you can see, it is simply using the zRssReader plugin to load posts into a div when the 'Get Posts' button is clicked.  Everything works fine, the display name is populated and the posts show up as expected.

Where I am having trouble is when I try to eliminate the button and try to load the posts at creation time.  If I place the plugin call in the activate function, I get no results.  I assume this is because the view is not fully loaded, so the element doesn't exist. I have two questions:

1. How do I delay the execution of the plugin call until the view is fully composed?
2. Even better, how do I load the plugin result into an the posts observable rather than using the query selector?  I have tried many combinations but no luck

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT** the below answer is for durandal 1.2.  In durandal 2.0 `viewAttached` has changed to `attached`

---

Copy pasted directly from durandaljs.com

"Whenever Durandal composes, it also checks your model for a function called `viewAttached`. If it is present, it will call the function and pass the bound view as a parameter. This allows a controller or presenter to have direct access to the dom sub-tree to which it is bound at a point in time after it is injected into its parent.

Note: If you have set `cacheViews:true` then `viewAttached` will only be called the first time the view is shown, on the initial bind, since technically the view is only attached once. If you wish to override this behavior, then set `alwaysAttachView:true` on your composition binding."
--[quoted from the site](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Composition/)

---

There are many ways you can do it but here is just 1 quick and dirty way:

```
<section>
    <h2 data-bind="html: displayName"></h2>
     <h3 data-bind="html: posts"></h3>
     <button data-bind="click: getRss">Get Posts</button>
     <div id="rsstestid"></div>
</section>
```

and the code:

```
define(function (require) {
    var http = require('durandal/http'),
        app = require('durandal/app');

    var $rsstest;

    return {
        displayName: 'This is my RssTest',
        posts: ko.observable(),
        viewAttached: function(view) {
           $rssTest = $(view).find('#rsstestid');
        },
        getRss: function() {
           $rssTest.rssfeed('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews');
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: @Eval I tried your solution, but getting this error: TypeError: $rssTest.rssfeed is not a function. do you have any idea?

Comment: @user836349 make sure viewAttached function is being called. Durandal should call this method as part of the composition lifecycle.  Then make sure that the $(view).find('#rsstestid'); is getting a reference to the dom element. The problem lies in 1 of those 2 actions.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I think it's wise to refrain from directly touching UI elements from within your view model.

A good approach is to create a custom KO binding that can render the rss feed.  That way, you're guaranteed that the view is in place when the binding executes.  You probably want to have the feed url exposed as a property on your view model, then the custom binding can read that when it is being updated.

Custom bindings are pretty simple - if I can do it, then it must be :)

Here's a link to the KnockOut custom bindings quickstart: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Answer (score 0):

I too am having the same problem, I'm trying to set a css property directly on an element after the durandal view model and view are bound together. I too assume that it's not working because the view is not fully composed at the point I am setting the value.

Best I have come up with is using the viewAttached lifecycle event in durandal, which I think is the last event in the loading cycle of a durandal viewmodel, and then using setTimeout to delay the setting of the property still further.

It's a pretty rubbish workaround but it's working for now.

```
   var viewAttached = function (view) {
        var _this = this;

        var picker = new jscolor.color($(view).children('.cp')[0], {
            onImmediateChange: function() {
                _updateCss.call(_this, this.toString());
            }
        });
        picker.fromString(this.color());
        setTimeout(function() {
            _updateCss.call(_this, _this.color());
        }, 1000);
    };

    var activate = function (data) {
        system.log('activated: ' + this.selectors + ' ' + this.color());
    };
    var deactivate = function (isClose) {
        system.log('deactivated, close:' + isClose);
    };

    return {
        viewAttached: viewAttached,
        deactivate: deactivate,
        activate: activate,
        color: this.color
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with timing. On an initial page load, where a partial view was being loaded on the page I could call the viewAttached function and use jQuery to bind some elements within the partial view. The timing worked as expected

However, if I navigated to a new page, and then back to the initial page, the same viewAttached + jQuery method failed to find the elements on the page... they had not yet been attached to the dom.

As best as I have been able to determine (so far) this is related to the transition effects in  the entrance.js file. I was using the default transition which causes an object to fade out and a new object to fade in. By eliminating the fadeOutTransition (setting it to zero in entrance.js) I was able to get the viewAttached function to actually be in sync with the partial views attachment.

Best guess is that while the first object is fading out, the incoming object has not yet been attached to the dom but the viewAttached method is triggered anyway.