# When should I call jQueryUI decoration functions in DurandalJS?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, durandal

In the viewmodel.js file, I want to bind a datepicker on a textbox.

Here is the code

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'durandal/app',
    'services/logger',
    'jqueryui'
    ],
function ($, app, logger, jqueryui) {
function activate() {
    if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
    $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
        });
    }
    return true;
};
var vm = {
    activate: activate
};

return vm;
});
```

It appears the jquery and jqueryui are never called. What is wrong with my code? Should I start the jQuery and jQuery UI methods in the `activate()` section or somewhere else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140840/loading-jquery-plugin-result-into-durandal-view

Comment: Not a great answer. I'll keep waiting for a better solution. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your approach would work, it's not the better way to do it.

The better approach is to make a custom binding ( http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html ). If you don't want to do the binding by hand, there is a library ( I don't use it so i don't know if they work well ) that has bindings for jqueryui: http://gvas.github.com/knockout-jqueryui/index.html

Anyway, the binding for your example will be something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {},
            $element = $(element),
            $btn = $("<button class='btn' type='button'><i class='icon-calendar'></i></button>");
        $element.datepicker(options);
        $element.prop("readonly", true);
        $element.wrap("<div class='input-append' />");
        $element.after($btn);

        $btn.click(function () {
            $element.datepicker("show");
        });

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor(),
                current = $(element).datepicker("getDate");
            observable(current);
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).datepicker("destroy");
        });

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            current = $(element).datepicker("getDate");

        if (value - current !== 0) {
            $(element).datepicker("setDate", value);
        }
    }
};
```

And at the view:

```
<input type="text" id="yourid" data-bind="datepicker: yourobservable, datepickerOptions:{}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But where should I put this `ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker` statement? In `function activate()`?

Comment: The easiest way is to put it in a javascript file and include it in your script bundle after the include for knockout.

Comment: Then, why do you believe it is a better solution? The code is more tedious at least. Does it offer a performance enhancement or something?

Comment: Because it enforce the separation between the view and viewmodel, It makes your code reusable and as you can read here, it's the way to go:

https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/issues/74#issuecomment-14291074

Answer (score 3):

The solution is found.

I should place jQuery related statement under `viewAttached` function.

```
function viewAttached() {
    if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
        $('input[type=date]').datepicker();
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm interested to know after this decision was reached, some 18 months ago, how you feel about it now.  viewAttached is an event that, while convenient, lends itself to overuse and tightly couples your view and view model to one another.  The binding handler solution is generally more widely accepted.  How did this turn out for you?